# How to connect to WiFi on a fresh minimal debian system?

Tags: debian, wifi

I used `debian-10.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso` to setup my system.

I  want to connect to my WPA/WPA2 WiFi but every solution I read suggests tools like `wpa_supplicant`, `iw`, `nmcli`, `wpa_cli` and `iwctl`, but, none of these comes preinstalled in the minimal netinst system.

Is there a way to connect to a WPA/WPA2 WiFi with just preinstalled tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, the net installer you described does come with the software you mentioned but it doesn't come with non-free firmware that your WiFi card might need. Your WiFi won't work until that non-free firmware is provided.

You won't be able to see the packages that you described unless the PATH for your user includes /sbin. The normal user's PATH will not include /sbin. Starting with Buster, the command su no longer includes /sbin in PATH. For options, see the Changes portion of the Debian Wiki article "NewInBuster" at https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster.  I suggest using sudo -s.

To install the missing firmware during installation, there is another package at https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/10.4.0+nonfree/amd64/iso-dvd/ that I understand contains that non-free firmware. I haven't tried it myself, but the documentation states that it does.

If you do not want to reinstall, I think that the easiest way to install missing firmware is to invoke Synaptic, search for the name of the firmware, like iwlwifi, select, and apply. You may or may not need to restart after installing. You do, however, have the option of using apt instead of Synaptic. Many people choose to use apt install linux-firmware.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to connect to a WPA/WPA2 WiFi with just preinstalled tools?

It depend on your wifi card:

- If you wifi card require free software the answer is YES (isn't your case)
- If your wifi card require non-free software , you need an additional step see : [Net Inst With Third Party Network Driver](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/NetInstWithThirdPartyNetworkDriver) or use the *[unofficial alternative build](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/) includes non-free firmware*

The debian installer fail to configure the wifi network mean that your network card require non-free firmware.