# How can I connect to WiFi from Linux command line on fresh minimal install of Alma Linux 9 (device lo not available)?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, alma-linux

I installed a fresh Alma Linux 9.1 installation from a minimal ISO (downloaded using the torrent on [this page](http://mirror.its.dal.ca/almalinux/9.1/isos/x86_64/)), and installed the OS on my laptop.

How can I connect to my WiFi on this fresh installation?

I looked at [this article](https://ostechnix.com/connect-and-disconnect-wifi-from-commandline-in-linux/), and tried

```
nmcli c up <name of my wifi>
```

This failed with

```
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection (device lo not available because device is strictly managed)
```

I tried [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/881581), but it failed:

```
# iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
bash: iface: command not found
```

My PATH includes `/sbin` (which [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598693/392334) mentioned might not be the case when running as root), so I don't think that could be the cause of `iface` not being found.

I also tried `ifconfig lo up`, but that did not change the output of `nmcli c up`. `ifconfig lo down && ifconfig lo up` also did not change the output of `nmcli c up`.

I also tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1190557/1081385) and added

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

to the end of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, again with no change to the output of `nmcli c up`.

My system has no `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

All commands I ran were as root.

What can I do to connect to the WiFi, without installing any programs not already available in my system (my laptop has no ethernet port)?

**Edit:**

Requested output of `ip link` (note that I may have typos - I can't copy-paste off my other computer, since I don't have a GUI yet):

```
1: lo: <LOOKBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp2s0 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b9:8a:60:eb:ab:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: AlmaLinux isn't Debian-based but RHEL-based. So avoid any Q/A related to Debian or Ubuntu. Forget about `lo`: it's not a Wifi interface. Check the output of `ip link` (or maybe `/sbin/ip link`) and see what other interfaces are displayed beside lo. If there is no other, a probable (but not certain) cause for this is that you lack some kernel option or required firmware to have your Wifi device detected properly. Can't tell more. Maybe try again installing with the DVD iso instead of the minimal iso.

Comment: This ^^^ People installing this or any other distro using any "minimal ISO" should know 1. Exactly *why* they're using it *in lieu* of the "normal" installation media and 2. Understand that minimal implies a very barebones installation intended to provide only a system that boots and everything else should be done/installed on demand by users according to their needs.

Comment: @A.B Please see my edit with the output of `ip link`. Is `wlp2s0` a WiFi interface? [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/723182/1081385) seems to suggest it is an Ethernet interface, and not a WiFi interface. (Though, as per your warning above, askubuntu Q/A might be of no value to me with my Alma Linux install.) If it is a WiFi interface, what should I do to connect using it?

Comment: It's a Wifi interface as the w tells (and as your own link tells). The MAC address is phony. the first byte's lower bit is set meaning it's a multicast address which is forbidden as source. I don't know if that's the cause of the problems or something else.

Comment: Anyway in case that was just a typo, I'm out of clue but I hope somebody else will help. Meanwhile, you really should try using the full DVD iso, so you can install whatever's missing if anything.